# Grocery products per year

Tags: data-request, historical, food, global, products

I'm looking for historical open data on food products you can find in supermarkets (like the data available on [openfoodfacts.org](https://world.openfoodfacts.org)).
The idea would be to know which products have been commercialized in 1990, 2000, 2010... to study the evolution of palm oil in food composition.